# Xpath: selecting nodes that have a certain child node

Tags: xml, xpath, pugixml

Using the pugixml library, I am trying to select all nodes that fit:

```
//v6_root_object/v6_rootlist2d/obj_pluginobject[@level='0']
```

that have a child node described by

```
//v6_root_object/v6_rootlist2d/obj_pluginobject[@level='0']/chunk[@id='110064']/string[@v='light']
```

Is there an easy way to do this in xpath?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way :

```
//v6_root_object/v6_rootlist2d/obj_pluginobject
    [
     @level='0' 
            and 
     chunk[@id='110064']/string[@v='light']
    ]
```

simply add child node XPath (relative to it's parent node) in the XPath criteria (within `[]`).